# Stange behaviour about ng-content

Tags: angular, angular6

Suppose to have this angular code :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let ..."></ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="execute()"></ng-container>
```

I wanto to execute FIRST the *ngFor calculate something and after i want do execute *ngIF. The *ngIf function execute use some values that are calculated from *ngFor.So we need after execute the *ngFor and after I need to exectue *ngIf. The problem is that *nif is called first that *ngFor has begin. Anyone can help me?

Comment: do you have two ng-containers? or both ngIf and ngFor are for the same container?

Comment: @Aragorn in the same container!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ideally you should handle this case in ts file. However here is the alternative way do so -

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let ...; let last = last">
        ....
    <ng-container *ngIf="last ? execute() : null"></ng-container> <!-- Execute at last index -->
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for not nesting the ngIf

Answer (score 0):

What you likely want is something like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let.... ">
  <div *ngIf="execute">
       //your stuff here....
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: @Aragon I can't do in this why because the execute method in *ngIf must be evaluate with a value that is obtain after the *ngFor

Comment: @Doflamingo19 Updated the answer, so you need if within the ngFor

Comment: @Doflamingo19 - I meant I updated the answer...try it out

Comment: I need to calculate the *ngFor after and we I obtain some values I can execute *ngif

Comment: You mean finish the ngFor loop and then go to another block that has ngIf?